# Install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows XP Pro - No option

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, windows-xp

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to install Ubuntu along side Windows XP Pro from a DVD.  I've read the installation guide but I don't have an option for installing alongside Windows. I see options for:

- Replace Microsoft Windows XP Professional with Ubuntu
- Encrypt the new Ubuntu Installation for Security
- Use LVM with the new Ubuntu Installation
- Something Else

If I check "Something Else", I see 2 lines that say /dev/sda and /dev/sda1.  The first one is blank and the second is ntfs and says size-80015 MB, used-unknown, system-Microsoft Windows XP Professional.

This is an 80GB hard drive.  I'm guessing that i'm not getting "install alongside windows" option because the drive is 1 partition using all the space.  I'm could be wrong.

Is dual-boot the same thing as installing alongside?  I mean, you can only boot one OS at a time right?

Any ideas how I should proceed?  I appreciate any help.  I can't wait to get Ubuntu running so I can start crankin' on some Ruby apps.

Comment: No, you're right, the disk is fully occupied by Windows. And, yes dual-boot is the same as installing alongside. You will need to either resize yoour partitions (which is rather complicated so I'll leave that for someone else to answer), or reinstalling both systems (do prefer to first install Windows, *then* Ubuntu, though).

Answer (score 0):

assuming your guess of hard disk(80 gb) beeing unpartitioned...... 
on your windows right click on my computer icon select the manage option.
a new window will appear in which select storage devices->disk management.
your 80 gb partition will be displayed .
right click on the partition ,select the option shrink volume to your required size.
format the new partition.
now insert ubuntu live cd and you will get the option "install along side of windows" option.
hope it will work.